# Опечатка на странице описания очередей проверок

Tags: дефект, локализация, справка

На [странице](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) в абзаце, описывающем запоздалые ответы, опечатка в слове "проверке".

> ...  процессу проверк**е** можно гарантировать...

Исправленный вариант - проверк**и**